# How to get Max date with selected row id in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, maxdate

I have a scenario in which i want to get Maximum Date but not from Whole Table Just from Selected id but i failed.

Here is my table

[image]

I run This Query For get my selected id

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_methodology` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6, `col_select_corporate`)
```

and i got that result

[image]

**From that result I want to get that record which have maximum Date**

I try that query but it not working for me

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_methodology` WHERE  id IN (1,5,7) AND `col_date` = (
    SELECT MAX(`col_date`)
    FROM `tbl_methodology`)
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: It is very bad db design, to save values as CSV

Comment: Yeah. Fix that !!!!

Comment: `SELECT MAX(col_date) FROM tbl_methodology WHERE  id IN (1,5,7) FROM tbl_methodology)`

Comment: You can use `order by` like as `SELECT * FROM tbl_methodology WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6, col_select_corporate) order by date desc limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the where clause twice and you should get the result you expected:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_methodology` WHERE  id IN (1,5,7) AND `col_date` = (
    SELECT MAX(`col_date`)
    FROM `tbl_methodology` WHERE  id IN (1,5,7))
```

And as i commented: **it is very bad db design, to save values as CSV**

Comment: i am new in Programming. That is my learning stage. Thanks for your suggestion. Thank you so much :)